# Gradle Multi-Module project call a common tasks from sub-modules

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I have a multi-module setup for a Java project with following structure.

```
mainApp
|--> core-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|       
|--> lib-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|--> lib-another-module
|       |--> src
|       |--> build.gradle
|       |--> gradle.properties
|--> settings.gradle
|--> build.gradle
```

in `mainApp/build.gradle` I've trying

```
task('collectBundles', type: Copy) {
    dependsOn "core-module:jar","lib-module:jar","lib-another-module:jar"
        
    into "$buildDir/image/"

    into("lib") {
        from project('core-module').file('build/libs/core-module.jar')
        from project('lib-module').file('build/libs/core-module.jar')
        from project('lib-another-module').file('build/libs/lib-another-module.jar')
    }
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

this `dependsOn` I'm trying to solve but I'm getting errors

```
task('collectBundles', type: Copy) {
    dependsOn subprojects.finaAll { it.tasks.findByName("jar") }
        
    into "$buildDir/image/"

    into("lib") {
        from project('core-module').file('build/libs/core-module.jar')
        from project('lib-module').file('build/libs/core-module.jar')
        from project('lib-another-module').file('build/libs/lib-another-module.jar')
    }
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Even I tried `dependsOn subprojects.findResult { it.tasks.findByName("jar") }`

I'm getting errors as

````
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'connectors'.

> Could not find method register() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy}, collectBundles, build_9f9pperbss2o8q2l4apsb5p9d$_run_closure15@c3c2ad7] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
> ```
````

Comment: Where is `findResult` defined? In your first example, I guess you are using [`findAll`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)), however you probably should use [`collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)), as `findAll` works as a filter and won't return the tasks but the subprojects.

Comment: Oh, I thought it is `Gradle API`